# How to get users and profile table data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have two tables: one is `users` and other is `user_profile` and in `users` table suppose 20 row and `user_profile` table only two rows.

How could I get all user which has profile or whom has no profile in **codeingniter**?

Comment: Please modify your question and include what you have already tried that isn't working as you expect it to.

Comment: Dunno about CI - but it sounds like a `LEFT JOIN` where the id on the profile table `IS NULL`

Comment: you should use `left join` of `ci` as `$this->db->join('Table', 'table.column = table.column', 'left');`

Comment: Thank i got answer form left join hint
 $this->db->select('users.id,users.first_name,user_profiles.bank_name,user_profiles.account_number');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('user_profiles','user_profiles.user_id=users.id','Left');
        $query=$this->db->get();

Answer (score 0):

**You can use join as below**

*Note :  `user_id` is primary key of users table*

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('user_profile up', 'up.user_id = u.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->get('users u')->result_array();
```

Comment: why we use up or users u 
i am getting  error please explain

Comment: but i get result form you left join hint thanks 

$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('user_profiles','user_profiles.user_id=users.id','Left');
        $query=$this->db->get();

Answer (score 0):

To get the users with profile, use INNER JOIN

```
 public function users_profile(){
        $this->db->select('users.*, user_profile.column1 as column1, user_profile.column2 as column2');
        $this->db->join('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id = users.user_id', 'inner');

        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

To get all users with or without profile, use LEFT JOIN

```
public function all_users(){
        $this->db->select('users.*, user_profile.column1 as column1, user_profile.column2 as column2');
        $this->db->join('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id = users.user_id', 'left');

        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Rememer to make user_id the **PRIMARY KEY** for both tables